# Http requests randomly hanging in browser, what are possible causes?

Tags: javascript, http, fetch-api, fastify

I have a very unusual issue, my web application (Made with ReactJS, Webpack and a Fastify backend) sometimes hangs infinitely (request pending) after making a request to the backend API.

Fastify serves both static files (compiled by webpack) and API routes.

It doesn't seem to matter which routes I call.

I tried in Chrome and Firefox both have the issue of showing the request as pending.
However Postman doesn't have this issue and when I use Burp Proxy there's no issue either...

[image: Pending Request in Chrome]

From that screenshot it looks like it hangs while trying to make the TCP handshake, however the server did receive the request, so I don't understand how this is possible?

Fastify reports the reply as sent: console.log(reply.sent) outputs "true"
But it seems to never reach the browser.

I'm using the fetch api.

Not sure which part of the code would be the culprit here, either it's the fetch frontend or some header that is ignored by Postman and removed by the proxy...

I just don't know where to look since I can't seem to replicate this bug consistently and it seems to make no sense.

Any idea what else could be the source of this problem ? In production we'll use Nginx as a proxy, but it's still an annoying issue in local development and it's a concerning bug since we don't understand what is actually happening.

The function I call frontend to make requests:

```
export const fetcher = async (url, method = 'GET', body = null) => {
    const res = await fetch(url, {
        method,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
            // If the user is authenticated the browser will add Cookies here
        },
        body: body ? JSON.stringify(body) : null,
    });

    if (!res.ok) {
        let err = await res.json();
        if (err.message) throw err;
        else return err;
    }
    return res.json();
};
```

Exemple of use :

```
<button
    onClick={async () => {
        let document = await fetcher(`/api/information/${docId}`);
        alert(`${document.title} is the title of my document !`);
    }}
/>
```

1: User clicks on button with a docId = 1, call is made, alert the title of the document
2: A few seconds later user press the button again with the same docId (1), except this time nothing happens, the request is hanging and the Promise is never resolved.
3: User doesn't understand why it doesn't work, press the button again (Chrome lets the request stall since another identical request is pending)
4: User press the button with docId = 2, this time the call goes through and alert the title of document 2
5: The request made at step 3 stop being stalled by the browser goes through and alert the title of document 1

The request made at step 2 is still pending, the server did receive it, did retrieve the document from the database and performed everything it needed to before sending a response. It even reports the reply has being sent.

EDIT (WIRESHARK RESULTS)
No response packets were received when the request hangs.

Here are the only differences between the 2 request paquets:

- Frame Number (expected)
- Frame Time (expected)
- IP checksum and IP ID (?)
- TCP Acknowledgement Number (?)
- TCP checksum (?)
- TCP Sequence number (?)
- TCP window size (?)
- Relative TCP time (?)
- TCP segment (?)

Another thing I noticed is that there seems to be a TCP communication every 3 seconds or so even without any interaction with the website. (just a few bytes ~70) (ACK)

I don't really know how to interpret any of this

Comment: Have you tried using a packet capture tool to see what's being sent and received? That will help you determine where in the process it's hanging.

Comment: Does it hung after few clicks? I suspect come resources exaution

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Usually the first call works everytime and the second call is often the problematic one. Sometimes it could also take 20 calls until it hangs, but most of the time it hangs after 2 calls. However I don't need to be spam clicking, even if I wait a full 30 seconds between 2 clicks it can still happen.

Comment: @Barmar I haven't tried, I'll try installing Wireshark and see if I can figure it out, I never did this kind of debugging, I'll report back with my findings if any.